# Future<String> argument to java

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Is there any way to send argument of `Future<String>` to Java with channel? I have this code:

```
  Future<String> returnName(String dbName) async {
    return await platform.invokeMethod("getBatteryLevel");
  }
```

And I want send argument dbName to java. Is it possible? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible you can find out in the official documentation (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) for more details, for now I leave you an example:

**Dart Class**

```
 static const platform = const MethodChannel('channel/example');

 Future<void> returnName(String dbName) async {
    return await platform.invokeMethod("sendDBName", <String, dynamic>{'data': dbName});
 }
```

So you are sending an object with the value of dbName.

**Java Class**

```
private static final String CHANNEL = "channel/example";

@Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
       if (call.method.equals("sendDBName")) {
         String dbName = call.argument("data");
       }
    }
}
```

Here you are receiving the object sent from Dart.